# Вывод дополнительного поля на странице категорий

Tags: php, opencart

Я создал дополнительное поле в админке (в котором есть краткое описание для товара), на странице продукта это поле вывел, работает нормально. Но на странице категорий не могу вывести, нечего нет даже ошибки в консоли. Причем если я вывожу к примеру параметр (sku, model) то есть любое встроенное поле, то она выводится, а созданное мной поле нет. Причем на странице категорий используется фильтр (FilterPro), и при попытке вывести мое поле он ломается, но ошибки при этом нет. Кто знает подскажите

Comment: Куда в базе заносятся данные из доп.поля?

Comment: в базе они заносятся в таблицу oc_product

Comment: Покажите, как выводите эти данные в category.tpl

Comment: В файле контроллера фильтра goldprice:                                        
       $result[] = array(
    'product_id' => $product['product_id'],                    
                               'tax' => $tax,
    'sku'=>$product['sku'],
    'goldprice'=>$product['goldprice'],                                                          );
  }